# Using precompiled headers in gradle experimental

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface, gradle-experimental

I want to include a file "abc.h" in every header. So, how should I include this precompiled header. I searched for something like this

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs += ['./src/main/jni/abc']
            }
        }
    }
}

android.sources {
    cpp {
        preCompiledHeader += file("abc.h")
    }
}
```

But it is not working. Also how to port LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES?

Comment: Have you found a way to add precompiled header?